# How is a compiler related to the runtime system?

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime

A quick search on the role of compiler brings up the following:

> A compiler is a special program that processes statements written in a
>   particular programming language and turns them into machine language
>   or "code" that a computer's processor uses.

However, I also read that every language needs to have a target runtime system and programs written in that language execute in the context of the runtime system.

Adding up the two, it appears that a compiler converts programs into bits understandable by the runtime system and the runtime system acts as the agent interpreting the bits, translating them to the processor intructions. Is this correct? If not, how else are compiler and runtime system related?

And if the above is correct, it would imply the following:

1. two executables compiled from programs with identical logic written
   in different languages would not be identical
2. an average machine would have dozens of runtimes which doesn't seem to be the case.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The runtime is a set of libraries (for a specific language) already compiled to run on the machine (real or virtual). It doesn't do any interpretation, it is just there to be used if needed.

The compiler will translate the source code into machine code that will also run on the machine, and that may call functions or procedures defined in the already existing runtime.

> two executables compiled from programs with identical logic written in different languages would not be identical

Most likely.

> an average machine would have dozens of runtimes which doesn't seem to be the case.

It could have dozens if the programmer uses dozens of different languages. But I don't think it is the common case.

Comment: about the last part, heres how I meant it : an average user installs programs from multiple different locations, each of which could be written using different languages ...so the runtime libraries would be shipped along with the programs?

Comment: Yes we could say it works that way. But I don't think it scales to dozens. Yoy should need one per language. For example Visual Basic and Visual C have runtimes that can be distributed by the developer. In the case of Java the runtime comes with JVM and you install it directly from Oracle for example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are suffering from a confusing book.

Here you have hit an ambiguity.

> However, I also read that every language needs to have a target runtime system and programs written in that language execute in the context of the runtime system.

[Rhetorical question] What is a "runtime system?" Is that the underlying hardware/operating system combination? Is it some runtime support for the specific language?

> Adding up the two, it appears that a compiler converts programs into bits understandable by the runtime system and the runtime system acts as the agent interpreting the bits, translating them to the processor intructions. Is this correct? If not, how else are compiler and runtime system related?

Again that depends upon what "runtime system" means. All programs require calls to the operating system (even if they are behind the scenes from the programmer).

Some programming languages require a much greater support and have libraries that are essentially drive the program. However, these are function calls, not bit interpretation.

> And if the above is correct, it would imply the following:
>   two executables compiled from programs with identical logic written in different languages would not be identical

That is almost always if not always the case.

> an average machine would have dozens of runtimes which doesn't seem to be the case.

That depends upon what you mean by "runtime." If it is a library of support functions for a specific programming language, then YES. If you mean something that interprets bits, then NO.